# capital and small letters using the acronym-package

Tags: acronyms

I am intending to use the package `acronym` for both, abbreviations and nomenclature.

While abbreviations are always capitalized, words that appear in the nomenclature aren't.

How can I make `acronym` ignoring the capitalization of the first letter. So that in following example?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\begin{document}
\ac{Test} is a \ac{test}.
\begin{acronym}
\acro{test}{only one definition of a test is listed here. No 'not found'
wanings for the \ac{Test}}
\end{acronym}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't see any similarity... but maybe i dont understand the linked question/problem.. What I need is basically a capitalized short-form which also matches the lower-case occurrence in \ac{}/acs{}..

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. Do you mean you want `\ac` to ignore the label case?

Comment: is the label the acronym printed bold on the left side of the acronym-list?.. yes I think that is what i want.. so \ac{car} should be recognized as an occurance of the acronym defined as \acro{Car}{brummbrumm} vice versa..

Comment: Okay, I understand what you're asking now. I can't think of a solution off the top of my head, but I've deleted my original comment just in case some over-enthusiastic user notices it and automatically votes to close without looking at the rest of the comments.

Comment: I have an idea but would you be happy to define your acronym label as `Cat` instead of `cat`?

Comment: what do you mean?... All labels to start with an upper-case letter? yes it is possible... for verbs it should look strange.. but if this is the only way to go..

Comment: i tried switching to glossaries-package and acro-package... but they have different weaknesses...

Comment: I've had a little play and (i) it's beyond me in any sensible timescale; (ii) my last comment made no sense, but it was based on half-remembered case-changing code

Comment: ok thank you. I think i will go for the package acro